# Solve Image CAPTCHA with CV2 and Tesseract OCR

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, captcha, opencv

I've been trying to solve the following captcha using cv2 to edit the picture and then using tesseract OCR to read the text in the image. Below is an example:

[image: captcha1]
[image: captcha2]

So far I've tried the following code to edit the images and improve ocr performance:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter 
def prepare_image(img):
    """Transform image to greyscale and blur it"""
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE)
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE)
    if 'L' != img.mode:
        img = img.convert('L')
    return img

def remove_noise(img, pass_factor):
    for column in range(img.size[0]):
        for line in range(img.size[1]):
            value = remove_noise_by_pixel(img, column, line, pass_factor)
            img.putpixel((column, line), value)
    return img

def remove_noise_by_pixel(img, column, line, pass_factor):
    if img.getpixel((column, line)) < pass_factor:
        return (0)
    return (255)


img = Image.open("captcha.png")
img = prepare_image(img)
img = remove_noise(img, 115)
img.save("result.png")
```

Which has the following result:

[image: result1]
[image: result2]

This improves tesseract reading but still, it isn't enough for reading the text in image. Any ideas on how can I solve this problem and read the text in image to solve the captcha? Thank you!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680624/captcha-preprocessing-and-solving-with-opencv-and-pytesseract